# Extract number and separate with comma from list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

List listFinal = [];

So listFinal have values from multiple list inside like below.
[["test: 111-333-5555", "test2: 222-333-4555"], ["test3: 555-333-2222"]]

How do I make this list so that it only extract numbers and separate with comma?

End result should be like
[1113335555, 2223334555, 5553332222]

I can think of trimming or regexp but not sure how to pull this off.

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
void main() {
  List<String> numberList=[];
  List<List<dynamic>> demoList=[["test: 111-333-5555", "test2: 222-333-4555"], ["test3: 555-333-2222"]];
   for(int i=0;i<demoList.length;i++){
        numberList.addAll(demoList[i].map((e) => e.toString().split(":")[1].replaceAll("-", "")).toList());
    }
  print(numberList.toString());
}
```

Comment: Some tips: The type annotations on the variables are not recommended for idiomatic Dart code (https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-type-annotating-initialized-local-variables). The `.toString()` call for an argument to `print()` is not necessary. The call to `.toList()` in an argument to `.addAll()` is not necessary. The `e.toString()` is not necessary because `e` is already a String - this would be clear if you hadn't typed the local variable as `List<List<dynamic>>` but had let it get inferred as `List<List<String>>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to get you started. This doesn't handle things like malformed input strings. First step is to "flatten" the list with `.expand`, and then for each element of the flattened iterable use a regex to extract the substring. Other options might include using `.substring` to extract exactly the last 12 characters of the String.

You can see this in action [on dartpad.](https://dartpad.dev/53fa961bff099f9b312f2d39f138ea4e)

```
void main() {
  final input = [
    ['test: 111-333-5555', 'test2: 222-333-4555'],
    ['test3: 555-333-2222']
  ];

  final flattened = input.expand((e) => e); // un-nest the lists

  // call extractNumber on each element of the flattened iterable,
  // then collect to a list
  final result = flattened.map(extractNumber).toList();

  print(result);
}

final _numberRegExp = RegExp(r'.*: ([\d-]+)$');

int extractNumber(String description) {
  var numberString = _numberRegExp.firstMatch(description).group(1);
  return int.parse(numberString.replaceAll('-', ''));
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that you wanted these as `ints`. Updated the dartpad.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this in a simple way.

```
  List<List<String>> inputList =  [
    ["test: 111-333-5555", "test2: 222-333-4555"], 
    ["test3: 555-333-2222"]
  ];
  List resultList = [];
  
  print('Input List : $inputList');
  
  inputList.forEach((subList){
    subList.forEach((element){
      var temp = element.split(' ')[1].replaceAll('-', '');
      resultList.add(temp);
    });    
  });
  
  print('Output List : $resultList');
```

Here I have taken your list as inputList and stored the result in resultList.
For each element of inputList we get a sub-list. I have converted the elements of that sub-list into the needed format and added those into a List.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Some tips: We typically avoid using `.forEach` with a function literal inside it (https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal). `String.split()` returns a list so there is no need to call `.toList()` following `.split()`. For the final string the idiomatic approach is interpolation instead of using `+` on Strings. `print('Output List : $resultList');` (https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-using-interpolation-to-compose-strings-and-values)